# How to create multiple Azure VMs using same ARM template through automation in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-resource-manager, azure-virtual-machine

I want to automate VM creation process with same ARM template. ARM template will be executed from ADO. How to automate VM creation? e.g. If I have to create 10 VMs with different name and same configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create an object type parameter to loop the vmName for [deploy the ARM template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/azure-resource-manager-template-deployment-v3?view=azure-pipelines) and override the vmName of the template.
YAML like:

```
trigger:
- none

parameters:
- name: VMs
  type: object
  default: [vm1,vm2]  
  
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- ${{ each VM in parameters.VMs }}:
  - task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
    inputs:
      deploymentScope: 'Resource Group'
      azureResourceManagerConnection: 'serive connection'
      subscriptionId: 'subid'
      action: 'Create Or Update Resource Group'
      resourceGroupName: 'RG name'
      location: 'East US'
      templateLocation: 'Linked artifact'
      csmFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/template/vmteplate.json'
      csmParametersFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/template/vm.parameters.json'
      overrideParameters: -vmName "${{VM}}" # string. Override template parameters. 
      deploymentMode: 'Incremental'
```

Or you can try to find [create multiple instances](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/copy-resources).